# Placing Java objects on Redis: is JavaNode a correct approach?

Tags: java, redis, jackson

I'm writing a JSON representation of an object to a Redis instance (via Jesque) but am unclear whether putting a `JsonNode` object is the right approach.  The gist of examples/APIs (e.g. [this one](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for `ObjectMapper`) is that I should use that if writing to a file, but I'm really looking for an Object I can send to Redis.

Here is what I have, where the `JsonNode` is represented below by the object `payload`.  This works just fine but was a struggle to figure out so I assume I'm missing the happy path.

```
final String queueName = "myQueue";
final net.greghaines.jesque.client.Client client = getClient();
final net.greghaines.jesque.Job job = new Job(jobClassName, payload);
client.enqueue(queueName, job);
client.end();
```

Currently `payload` is a `JsonNode` object generated by

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Object jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(this);
```

Is there a more preferred approach?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to storing the `JsonNode` representation of your object is to simply store a `String` representation:

`new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourObject);`

Then, when you retrieve the object, you can always deserialize the `String` representation to a `JsonNode` if you need to:

`JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString);`

Or to a simple type-safe entity object:

`YourEntity entity = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, YourEntity.class);`

All without storing library specific information in Redis.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that initially but my Redis consumer had issues, namely the `String` itself was being put on the queue instead of a hash representation of the object.  And the consumer is a Ruby client over which I have no control.  My issue may be a confluence of (mis)use of Redis, Jackson and Jesque APIs.

Comment: I see - that makes sense, and that sounds like an problem in interacting with Redis - which can probably be sorted. From the POV of the consumer - does it have an easier time with `JsonNode`?

Comment: The Ruby client consumes the payload without issue when I put a `JsonNode` object. I don't understand exactly what gets put on the queue when I use `JsonNode`, but from a blackbox perspective it seems to be a JSON representation of my pojo (instead of a JSON representation of a `JsonNode` object itself) so that works for me.

Comment: Well, then it depends on how much time you want to invest looking into this - go deeper and see what exactly gets stored into Redis, and why your Ruby client isn't able to consume the Strings, or - seeing how it works - you could leave the `JsonNode` as it is, even if it's not the cleaner way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen.  I will update this question if I get the cycles to dig deeper, and if I figure it out eventually. I likely need to dig deeper into the Jackson documentation to narrow my field of investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) it has built-in [Redis based scheduler](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services/#94-distributed-scheduled-executor-service) and works with Json, Kryo, msgpack and many other codecs. Provides most easier api for Redis power.